# Does HashPack wallet support a subscription model?

Tags: subscribe, nft, ticket-system, hedera-hashgraph, hashpack

I am building an NFT platform and planning to use a subscription approach for users who want to access the platform. Instead of keeping the traditional payment gateway (stip / paypal) I would like to use the HashPack wallet to make payments for subscriptions in USDC. What would you suggest?

I did not try anything yet, but I know the traditional approach and I can sense that it can be implemented in this wallet based one. The only concern is whether this wallet integration leads any difficulties of coding and user experiences.